# Making my site (which is 480px wide) scale perfectly on mobile safari

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

The main body of my site is 480px wide - see example here: http://5things.me/

It should fit perfectly on the iphone, but somehow the default view seems to be using a far wider grid.

I am showing 2 images below - the first one is what it currently appears as, the second one is what is should appear as.

I should not need to do too much mobile customization, since the whole site is only 480px wide =)

[image: current]

[image: desired]

Comment: and that, kids, is why you shouldn't design for specific pixel size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Look here for more iPhone-related tags:
http://www.omiod.com/iphone/dev-notes.php

Comment: Actually, that did not work very well. because it worked well only in landscape mode. in protrait mode, you could only see 2/3 of the screen

<meta name="viewport" id = "viewport" content = "maximum-scale=0.6667; width=480"/>

this worked better =)